# Remove/revoke GitHub OAuth 'access_token'

Tags: java, android, github, authorization

I am using this GitHub's API to generate an access token for the user (mobile app), using this tutorial:

- https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#authorizing-oauth-apps

I am using a built-in webpage so the user can log in with username and password. After that, the user receives an access_token that can be used to access GitHub scopes (in my case, profile info).

The response:

```
{"access_token":"1234token1234", "scope":"user", "token_type":"bearer"}
```

But when the user logs out of the app, I want to delete/revoke this token. How can I do that?

I only found this answer here:

[Revoking OAuth Access Token Results in 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217750/revoking-oauth-access-token-results-in-404-not-found)

But it is from 2013, and it is not working.

Any ideas on how to solve this? (Sorry for the English guys, Brazilian guy here o/)

Answer (score 5):

For future people seeking the same answer, I contacted GitHub support and they helped me solve my problem.

Deleting/revoking an `access_token`:

This is handled using the `Client ID`, and the `Client Secret` tied to the OAuth application:

```
curl \
  -X DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -u CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET \
  https://api.github.com/applications/CLIENT_ID/token \
  -d '{"access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN"}'
```

More detailed explanation: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/oauth-applications#delete-an-app-authorization

Watch the URL suffix for the difference between `/grant` and `/token` (see the docs).

The access token will still allow you to fetch public information via the /user request, but any attempts to access restricted or private content will return an authorization error.

Comment: Is this still working? Your link redirects to a place that has nothing on revocation.

Comment: It is now in: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/apps#delete-an-app-authorization

Answer (score 0):

`<meta-data android:value="key_value" android:name="api_key"></meta-data>`

https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-hide-your-api-key-in-android-600583/

Good reference is:
https://gist.github.com/DomDerrien/1009626

This is how I'd add it in Java...
personally I wouldn't commit my api or auth tokens if to be sending it out

Comment: I know. :) This is not my real token. I explicitly put `1234token1234`. But next time, I will follow your advice.