# how to delete github oauth accessToken when user logout?

Tags: javascript, access-token, github-api, github-oauth

I'm having trouble with deleting github accessToken when user try to logout from my react app.
I was trying to follow the instructions in [github delete accesstoken](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/oauth-applications#delete-an-app-token) documents, but I get an 404 bad request.

I was trying to handle github logout by javascript in React App.
Here's the code.

```js
const handleGithubLogout = async() => {
        
        await axios.delete('https://api.github.com/applications/${mygithubClientId}/token',
            {data : {access_token:"${mygithubAccessToken}"}}
            ,
            {headers: {
                    Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
                }
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('succceed')
        })
        
        setTimeout(() => purge(), 100)

    }
```

The thing is ,in github document, they described how to delete github accessToken by cURL and javascript.

```
curl \
  -X DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/applications/Iv1.8a61f9b3a7aba766/token \
  -d '{"access_token":"e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a"}'
```

so I tried javascript code like below. but still gets the 404 response.

```js
const octokit = new Octokit({
             auth: '${myGithubAccessToken}'
           })
          
          await octokit.request(`DELETE /https://api.github.com/applications/{myClientID}/token`, {
             client_id: myClientID,
             access_token: myGithubAccessToken
           }).then(() => {
               console.log('success')
           })
```

I wonder how to change cURL code to javascript code.
I'm not sure I wrote the code correctly.
and also there is [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56230534/remove-revoke-github-oauth-access-token) in stackoverflow but I still don't get it how it works.

Answer (score 0):

See the provided javascript example code [in the documentation you linked to](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/oauth-applications#delete-an-app-token):

```js
// Octokit.js
// https://github.com/octokit/core.js#readme
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: 'personal-access-token123'
})

await octokit.request('DELETE /applications/{client_id}/token', {
  client_id: 'Iv1.8a61f9b3a7aba766',
  access_token: 'e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a'
})
```

Compared to that there are multiple issues in your code snippet:

- `auth: '${myGithubAccessToken}'` will assign the literal string `'${myGithubAccessToken}'` and not the value of `myGithubAccessToken`. Either use [template strings with backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or no quoting at all: `auth: myGithubAccessToken`
- the request URL specified is a domain-relative URL *containing* another absolute URL, i.e. it will be resolved to `https://api.github.com/https://api.github.com/applications/{myClientID}/token`. Either remove the leading `/` or - as in the example code - leave out the protocol and host part
- in the URL you specify `{myClientID}` as placeholder but only pass the `client_id`, so it won't be replaced properly. You have to use `{client_id}` instead

Comment: Thanks for checking my code. But it still doesn't work. Is there any chance not to use Octokit and delete github accessToken? I know there is an Octokit example for javascript on the github documents, but I want to try not to use octokit but still using javascript. So I was thinking sending axios request referencing by `curl` code which is described on my origin question. I'm not sure that's possible tho...